# I can call the control outside current class,but can't manipulate

Tags: c#, combobox

I have two classes.My aim is to change datasource of combobox but i first tested if i can see how many items combobox has simply but i couldn't do it.I am able to call a ComboBox outside the current class like:

```
public partial class secondclass: Form
{
      public secondclass()
      {
           firstclass first=new firstclass();
           MessageBox.Show(first.comboBox1.Items.Count.ToString())//it gives 0 item 
           //even if i have 5 items.
      }

}
public partial class firstclass: Form
{.....
}
```

Comment: did you add the items in design time?

Comment: yes and changed the modifier from private to public of combobox.

Comment: You get 0 items because you're making a new instancr of the form and asking about that combobox, that one is empty as its a new form

Comment: Maybe make a method in firstclass that returns the count and call that method from first class

Comment: and i can't reach combobox without instantiate the class contains it

Comment: The way you reach it it will always be empty look at the answer you need something like that

Answer (score 1):

you instantiated new Form here `firstclass first=new firstclass();`.
You need to have pointer to existing form that the comboBox is filled not new one that is empty. Send pointer of first class to second class when you instantiated second class as follow:

```
public partial class secondclass: Form
{
      public secondclass(firstclass first)
      {
           // firstclass first=new firstclass();
           MessageBox.Show(first.comboBox1.Items.Count.ToString())
      }

}
public partial class firstclass: Form
{
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondclass second = new secondclass(this); // Pointer to first class
    }
}
```